# Proving compactness of sets of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I have the following problem:

Let $X$ be the set of all bounded sequences of real numbers with the metric

$d(\{x_n\},\{y_n\}) = \sup\{|x_n-y_n|: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Which, if any, of the following subsets of $X$ is compact?

(1) The set $A$ of all convergent sequences

(2) The set $B$ of all sequences which converge to zero

(3) The set $C$ of all constant sequences

When I see this problem my first thought is that it is trivial, because for (1), (2), and (3) for each sequence in each set there will obviously be a convergent subsequence because the mother sequence is convergent. However, I'm not very familiar with working with sets of sequences, so am I actually going to be trying to figure out whether or not each sequence of sequences has a convergent subsequence? If so, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: I suspect the entire point of this exercise is to get you familiar with what you are not yet familiar. Otherwise, why waste time and money going to school anyway?

Comment: Can you cover any of the sets with finitely many balls of diameter $1$, say?

Comment: I don't have any idea what you mean by "mother sequence".  But this seems to be misleading you, since as it turns out, *none* of these sets is compact.

Comment: Oh! I think I get it, will I be using the property of compact sets that they must be closed and bounded? None of these sets appear to be bounded.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*  The continuous image of a compact set is compact, and the map $f\colon X\to\mathbb R$, $\{x_n\}\mapsto x_1$ is continuous.